# Is it possible to migrate a IIS web application to SharePoint?

Tags: iis, web-applications, sharepoint-online

I have a local web application which is running on IIS (on windows server 2012) since 2014 and using .NET framework.
Is there a way to host this web application in SharePoint Online ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can migrate your ASP.NET Web Application to SharePoint Online, you have to rebuild it from the scratch in SharePoint Online.

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Thank you for your answer, are you sure it is not possible ? If yes, can you tell me where (in SharePoint online) I can do this?

Comment: Yes i am sure it's not possible to migrate to SharePoint Online, you have to rebuild the Application in SharePoint Online.